# How to avoid implicit conversion when using XQuery value() method in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xquery

I have the following xml that I am parsing using TSQL - XQuery value method.

```xml
<Root>
  <FooAudit>
    <BarIntField>..</BarIntField>
    <BarDateTimeField>..</BarDateTimeField>
    <BarVarcharField>...</BarVarcharField>
    <BarFloatField>...</BarFloatField>              
  </FooAudit>            
</Root>
```

However, every time I invoke .value() it results in an implicit conversion.  How can I get rid of this implicit conversion since this logic will be called thousands of times per minute?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @BarIntField INT;
DECLARE @BarDateTimeField DATETIME;
DECLARE @BarVarcharField VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @BarFloatField FLOAT;

--Test with non null values
SET @BarIntField = 123;
SET @BarDateTimeField = GETUTCDATE();
SET @BarVarcharField = 'My Text';
SET @BarFloatField = 2.3;

--Test with null values
/*
SET @BarIntField = NULL;
SET @BarDateTimeField = NULL;
SET @BarVarcharField = NULL;
SET @BarFloatField = NULL;
*/

DECLARE @payload XML;

SET @payload =
(
    SELECT @BarIntField AS BarIntField,
           @BarDateTimeField AS BarDateTimeField,
           @BarVarcharField AS BarVarcharField,
           @BarFloatField AS BarFloatField
    FOR XML PATH('FooAudit'), ROOT('Root'), TYPE
);

--Implicit conversion here
DECLARE @parsedIntValue AS INT = @payload.value('(/Root/FooAudit/BarIntField/text())[1]', 'int');
PRINT @parsedIntValue;

--Implicit conversion here
DECLARE @parsedDateTimeValue AS DATETIME = @payload.value('(/Root/FooAudit/BarDateTimeField/text())[1]', 'DATETIME');
PRINT @parsedDateTimeValue;

--Implicit conversion here
DECLARE @parsedVarcharValue AS VARCHAR(25) = @payload.value('(/Root/FooAudit/BarVarcharField/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)');
PRINT @parsedVarcharValue;

--Implicit conversion here
DECLARE @parsedFloatValue AS FLOAT = @payload.value('(/Root/FooAudit/BarFloatField/text())[1]', 'FLOAT');
PRINT @parsedFloatValue;
```

Here is the [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ1TPAhld).

Comment: The fact it *says* "implicit conversion" doesn't mean it's implicit in the normal sense. You specified you wanted a conversion, that's what you got. Parsing XML in SQL Server thousands of times a minute doesn't sound like a good idea to start with. If you rewrite your question telling us *what you are actually trying to do* we may be able to help.

Comment: Trying to rapidly dequeue messages from service broker queue and concerned about the implicit conversion overhead.

Comment: Possibly using the `number()` or `data()` XQuery functions may speed it up, but I think this is a micro-optimization. Do you have an actual performance issue? Can you [edit] in your actual code, and describe your Service Broker setup in short?

Comment: sp_blitzcache shows the sp as top CPU consuming query and lists implicit conversion warning.

Comment: That just means that it's being executed a lot (total execution time), and happens to have that warning in it. Not necessarily that the warning is what's causing the perf issue, it could be anything. Putting it another way, the XML hierarchy itself is really slow, irrespective of a small data conversion If it's the only command in the whole SP then maybe. Let's see the code. Also if you're using `WAITFOR` that may screw up BlitzCache's calculations

Comment: You'll always see the **implicit conversion** warning in this context but as previously mentioned that doesn't necessarily mean it's causing issues. Usually the kind of issues that can result from that are **cardinality estimate** issues when the conversion is happening in predicates, but based on your query that doesn't seem to be your situation. Even if **sp_BlitzCache** is flagging it as your top **CPU** consumer, if that's the only thing running at that time and it's only using half the available **CPU** then it's an irrelevant metric that it's the top consumer, so it *can* be situational.

Comment: you can usually find more interesting queries if you sort by [avg cpu instead](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/sp_blitzcache-the-law-of-averages/).

Comment: it didn't occur to me earlier, but there's a lot of great information about querying xml in this talk, by the person who architected it in sql server: [Deep Dive into XQuery and XML in Microsoft SQL Server: Common Problems and Best Practice Solutions](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DBI404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the implicit conversion warnings, they are irrelevant here.  But parsing XML is not free, and you're doing it the best way possible in TSQL.

If you really need to improve the XML parsing, you'd have to try SQLCLR and the low-level [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0), or a [pre-compiled XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serializer-generator-tool-sgen-exe).